# An inequality for sum of positive semidefinite matrices

Tags: matrices, inequality, pseudoinverse, positive-semidefinite

If $A$ and $B$ are $p\times p$ positive semidefinite matrices of rank $p_{0}<p$. Let $A=P\operatorname{diag}(r_{1},\ldots,r_{p_{0}},0,\ldots,0)P^{\top}$, where $P$ is an orthonormal matrix, and define $A^{-1}=P\operatorname{diag}(1/r_{1},\ldots,1/r_{p_{0}},0\ldots,0)P^{\top}$. I want to show, for any $p$-dimensional vector $v$ with $P^{\top}v\not=0$,
$$
v^{\top}(A+B)^{+}v\leq v^{\top}A^{+}v,
$$
where $A^{+}$ is the Moore-Penrose pseudo inverse of $A$.

If $A$ and $B$ are positive definite, we can write $A=P\operatorname{diag}(r_{1},\ldots,r_{p})P^{\top}$ and $B=P\operatorname{diag}(u_{1},\ldots,u_{p})P^{\top}$, where $r_{i}>0$ and $u_{i}>0$ for all $i=1,\ldots,p$, and $P$ is orthonormal. Then we can re-define $v,A$ and $B$ as $P^{-1}v,\operatorname{diag}(r_{1},\ldots,r_{p})$ and $\operatorname{diag}(r_{1},\ldots,r_{p})$, respectively. Let $v=(v_{1},\ldots,v_{p})^{\top}$, we have
$$
v^{\top}(A+B)^{-1}v=\sum_{i=1}^{p}\frac{v_{i}^{2}}{r_{i}+u_{i}}\leq\sum_{i=1}^{p}\frac{v_{i}^{2}}{r_{i}}=v^{\top}A^{-1}v.
$$

When $A$ and $B$ are positive semidefinite, similar matrix decompositions still hold with some $r_{i}$'s and $u_{i}$'s are $0$. However, the above derivation cannot be used. I think the inequality still holds, but can anyone help me with the proof?

Any helps or hints are appreciated!

Comment: What are $d,d_0$? Surely if $A$ is invertible it has rank $p$?

Comment: @copper.hat Sorry for the typo... Should be $p_{0}$ and $p$...

Comment: In that case $A$ cannot be invertible.

Comment: Sorry again... I've added the definition of the inverse of a positive semidefinite matrix.

Comment: This is commonly referred to as the pseudo inverse or the Moore Penrose inverse.

Comment: There is no `\diag` command in MathJax; I've changed all instances of it to `\operatorname{diag}`.

Answer (score 1):

The statement that you want to prove isn't true. Counterexample: consider
$$
A=\pmatrix{1&0\\ 0&0},\ B=\pmatrix{1&1\\ 1&1},\ C=A^+-(A+B)^+=\frac14\pmatrix{3&-1\\ -1&-1}.
$$
When $v=(1,3)^\top$, we have $v^\top Cv=-3$.

In case $A$ is positive definite and $B$ is positive semidefinite, the statement is true, but your reasoning is wrong because $A$ and $B$ are not necessarily simultaneously orthogonally diagonalisable. The correct reasoning is to observe that $0\preceq A\preceq A+B$ and therefore $A^{-1}\succeq(A+B)^{-1}$.

Comment: Thanks. Looks like stronger conditions are needed...